# Chrome printing website, missing layout options

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, printing

I've been creating a website and a portion of the site is designed to be printed on tabloid paper in portrait mode. The problem I'm having is when the print dialog comes up in Chrome it's missing the "Layout" options.

In this screen shot, the left side shows how my dialog box looks vs. how it looks when I print other websites. The ironic thing is even other sites I've created have the option as shown on the right, which is the desired behavior.

[image: print dialog example]

My question is, what controls this behavior? How do I correct it? In searching the web the only mention I've see of this is when Chrome is displaying PDF files, but I'm displaying a web page.

Any insight you can give would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does you site have an `@media print` CSS rule?

Comment: can the moderators please un-close this question? This question and the answer below was extremely helpful to me and also others considering the number of upvotes. Also, this issue is most definitely programming-related as it has to do with CSS, `@print` and media declarations. I'm assuming the moderators weren't aware of this at the time, but this deserves to be a real question. Thanks

Comment: Voted to reopen as this revolves around a CSS property that has an impact in a browser... so it is not entirely different from any other CSS related question.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

If you have an `@page` size declaration in the print CSS, this will override (and hide) the orientation on the print dialog. To override a declaration that is set elsewhere (e.g. Bootstrap 4 does this) you can add:

```
@page {
  size: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly my problem!

Comment: This is to be put into a separate CSS rather than inline or else the declaration is ignored.

Comment: Note, this doesn't need to be in a `@media print` as it only applies to print anyway, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick addition to the accepted answer..

For those who are unable to edit the css of the page you're trying to print, you can install the Chrome extension called '**Stylus**' ([link here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne)), and create a new style with just the above suggestion:

```
​​​@page {
  size: auto;
}
```

This will enable the missing options from the print dialog on any/every web page..